# Как найти угол между векторами?

Tags: математика, геометрия

На входе есть 3 точки AOB (но я уже упростил все до векторов a и b).

Нужна полная версия без ограничений на тупые, острые, прямые и другие частные случаи углов. В идеале хочу получить угол от 0 до 360 градусов или от -180 до 180.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61634/discussion-on-question-by-irumba-----).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте возьмем какой-нибудь "опорный" ("стартовый") вектор, который будем считать за начало отсчета. Я взял вектор (1; 0) - это позволит упростить немного расчеты.
Код будет на C#:

```
struct Vector
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }

    public Vector(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x; Y = y;
    }

    public static readonly Vector Reference = new Vector(1, 0);

    // Угол в градусах относительно опорного, возвращает значение из диапазона (-180°; 180°]
    public static double AngleOfReference(Vector v)
        => Math.Atan2(v.Y, v.X) / Math.PI * 180;
}
```

Тогда угол между упорядоченной парой векторов будет вычисляться как:
`Vector.AngleOfReference(a) - Vector.AngleOfReference(b);`, но, как правильно подсказывает в комментариях @VladD, на выходе может получиться значение из диапазона (-360; 360], его нужно "нормализовать", поэтому всё-таки я добавлю в структуру метод для расчета угла:

```
public static double AngleOfVectors(Vector first, Vector second)
{
    var angle = AngleOfReference(first) - AngleOfReference(second);
    if (angle > 180) angle -= 360;
    if (angle <= -180) angle += 360;
    return angle;
}
```

Это даст нам угол точно из диапазона (-180°; 180°].

---

Еще одно небольшое улучшение, приведу полный код полученной структуры:

```
struct Vector
{
    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }

    public Vector(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x; Y = y;
    }

    public static readonly Vector Reference = new Vector(1, 0);

    public static double AngleOfReference(Vector v)
        => NormalizeAngle(Math.Atan2(v.Y, v.X) / Math.PI * 180);

    public static double AngleOfVectors(Vector first, Vector second)
        => NormalizeAngle(AngleOfReference(first) - AngleOfReference(second));

    private static double NormalizeAngle(double angle)
    {
        bool CheckBottom(double a) => a >= 0;
        bool CheckTop(double a) => a < 360;

        double turn = CheckBottom(angle) ? -360 : 360;
        while (!(CheckBottom(angle) && CheckTop(angle))) angle += turn;
        return angle;
    }
}
```

Внося корректировки в `NormalizeAngle` вы можете выбрать требуемый выходной диапазон. В коде выше он `[0°; 360°)`, если вам нужен `(-180°; 180°]`, то поправьте так:

```
bool CheckBottom(double a) => a > -180;
bool CheckTop(double a) => a <= 180;
```

Comment: А в каком промежутке получится угол?

Comment: @VladD, хм, согласен, сейчас дополню

Comment: @VladD там хак на знак минуса в конце. Так что от -180 до 180 )

Comment: @iRumba: Это у угла, а у разности?

Comment: А зачем так сложно вычислять AngleOfReference? Есть же Atan2(y, x). И заодно длину можно не вычислять.

Comment: @VladD, ну это уже мелочи, ТС может сам упростить себе и получить окончательный вариант

Comment: Ну, надо ж изящный вариант? :)

Comment: `public static double AngleOfReference(Vector v) => Math.Atan2(v.Y, v.X)`. (По желанию перевести в градусы.)

Comment: @VladD, уже исправил, убедили)

Comment: С учетом отсчета от опорного угла - вообще красота )

Comment: Ваще красота. Воспользовался формулой `Math.Atan2(b.X, b.Y) / Math.PI * 180 - Math.Atan2(a.X, a.Y) / Math.PI * 180;`. Я только не понял зачем там нужно искусственное приведение к диапазону (-180; 180], меня и 0-360 устраивает :)

Comment: @iRumba, приведение нужно, так как вы можете получить первый угол, например, `150`, а второй - `-100` и при вычитании получите `250`. В любом случае, если вам это нужно только для вращения фигур, то разницы абсолютно никакой. "Нормализация" (как я ее назвал) нужна для вывода значения пользователю (если вы ему это выводите), тут уж вы должны выводить значения строго из диапазона будь то (-180; 180] или [0; 360)

Comment: кстати, если будете использовать только одну формулу - можете вынести `/ Math.PI * 180` за скобки - выиграете полтакта процессора )

Comment: Спасибо, рефакторинг будет позже, пока надо "выкатить" :)

Answer (score 1):

Все элементарное - просто!

Вычисляем значение между векторами:

```
// создаем первый вектор
var start1 = new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 };
var end1 = new Point { X = 2, Y = 2 };
var vector1 = Vector.FromPoints(start1, end1);

// создаем второй вектор
var start2 = new Point { X = 2, Y = 2 };
var end2 = new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 };
var vector2 = Vector.FromPoints(start2, end2);

// вычисляем угол в радианах
var angleRad = Vector.CalculateAngleBetween(vector1, vector2);
// переводим угол в градусы
var angleDegree = angleRad / Math.PI * 180;

Console.WriteLine(angleDegree);
```

И классы `Point` и `Vector`:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class Vector
{
    public double X { get; private set; }

    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public double Length { get; private set; }


    private Vector(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;

        CalculateLength();
    }


    // вычисляет вектор по двум точкам
    public static Vector FromPoints(Point start, Point end)
    {
        return new Vector(start.X - end.X, start.Y - end.Y);
    }

    // вычисляет угол между веторами
    public static double CalculateAngleBetween(Vector vector1, Vector vector2)
    {
        if (vector1.Length == 0 || vector2.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(vector1.Length == 0 ? nameof(vector1) : nameof(vector2), "Vector can not be with zero lenght");
        }
        var scalarMultiplier = vector1 * vector2;
        var cos = scalarMultiplier / (vector1.Length * vector2.Length);
        var angle = Math.Acos(cos);

        return angle;
    }

    // вычисляет скалярное произведение векторов
    public static double operator *(Vector a, Vector b)
    {
        return a.X * b.X + a.Y * b.Y;
    }


    // вычисляет длину вектора
    private void CalculateLength()
    {
        var xPow2 = X * X;
        var yPow2 = Y * Y;
        var sum = xPow2 + yPow2;
        var sqrt = Math.Sqrt(sum);

        Length = sqrt;
    }
}
```

Онлайн калькулятор [тут](http://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/vector/angl/).

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zRtHPO)!

Comment: А зачем жутко медленный `Math.Pow` вместо быстрого умножения?

Comment: @VladD согласен, не подумал об этом. Исправил, спасибо.

Comment: а что будет, если Vector.Length == 0?

Comment: и еще... я вот открыл пример. Если я правильно понял, там 2 вектора (1; 1) и (-1; -1). Почему между ними угол ~360 градусов? Должен же быть 180. Разве нет?

Comment: Вроде вообще не правильно работает, вместо 90 выводит 180, вместо 180 - 360. 360 это полный оборот

Comment: @Андрей сорянчик, неверно с радиан в градусы переводил :) Подправил.

Comment: @iRumba согласен, мои вычисления радианы=>градусы подвели. Исправлено.

Comment: Есть еще кое что. Возьмем 2 вектора (1; 2) и (2; 1). Результат будет ~36 градусов. А вот если вектора поменять местами (2; 1) и (1; 2), то я ожидаю результат ~-36.

Comment: @iRumba, как я и говорил в комментариях к вопросу об отрицательных углах. В этом ответе как раз и вычисляется "классический" угол от 0 до 180.

Comment: @Андрей ага, я это сделал еще до того, как задал вопрос. Задал вопрос именно потому что мне нужен отрицательный угол. Я на форме беру фигуру и вращаю.. вот по часовой стрелке она таким способом вращается, а против часовой не хочет. А вы мне тут про правила и терминологии...

Comment: @iRumba, ну в моём ответе это учтено.

Comment: @iRumba как вы собираетесь высчитать отрицательное значение? Можете вычитать `v1.Y - v2.Y` и, если отрицательное - умножать угол на `-1`